# Rails 2.0.1, Pow.cx - config.ru error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-on-rails-2, rack-pow

I have rails 2.0.1 and the latest version of pow.cx setup and I'm getting an error which I think is related to the config.ru file:

```
  NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::Dispatcher
  ~/repos/selfsale-001/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:263:in `load_missing_constant'
  ~/repos/selfsale-001/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing'
  ~/repos/selfsale-001/config.ru:3
  ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
  ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
  ~/repos/selfsale-001/config.ru:1:in `new'
  ~/repos/selfsale-001/config.ru:1
```

my `config.ru` is:

```
# Rails.root/config.ru
require "./config/environment"
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

So ActionController isn't initialised, my question is what needs to be initialised for this setup? I have scoured Google and haven't found a config that works yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. my guess would be that you need to use at least Rails 2.3 to have a running Rack middleware, see

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html

So, for Rails earlier than 2.3, your config.ru can not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the info poseid, if I don't use a config.ru pow.cx asks for one. Does this mean I can't use pow.cx?

Comment: yes, as far as I know pow is a NodeJS based server for Rack applications. As you are using only Rails 2.0.x , you are not using a Rack compatible stack.